# are or were with 'recent' word?

Tags: british-english

Which word should be in the blank?

are or were?

I thought it should be 'were' but other teachers said that it should be 'are' because of the word 'recent'.

Almost all the shops located in this shopping centre _____ closed during the recent New Year period.

Comment: If your teachers really told you that, they are unqualified to teach you English. In other words, not only do they not understand English, but they are apparently unable even to read a dictionary! This is a very simple question. "Recent" means: **_Done or made in a period of the past comparatively close to the present._** (OED.) Because _the recent New Year period_ describes a time in the past, only the the past tense **were** can be correct. There is no other possible interpretation of this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase

> during the recent New Year period

would be used to refer to the time while New Year occurred in the past.  In your example is can only be referred to in the past

> Almost all the shops... **were** closed during the recent New Year period.

However, if the New Year period has already completed but the shops are still closed, it could be described as

> Almost all the shops... **are** closed *due to* the recent New Year period.
>   Almost all the shops... **are** closed during the *current* New Year period.

which is one possible explaination why other teachers might think "are" should be used.